# Partitioning finite directed graphs into 3 "incoming-sparse" sets

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a directed graph. For $v\in V$ set $\text{In}(v)=\{x\in V: (x,v)\in E\}$.

Is it possible to find a partition $P_1,P_2,P_3$ of $V$ such that for every $P_i$ and every vertex $v\in P_i$ we have $$|\text{In}(v)\cap P_i| \leq |\text{In}(v)\cap(V\setminus P_i)|$$?

Comment: It is very similar to your previous question on majority colouring, yes?

Comment: How may this hold when $In(v)$ is empty? Maybe, $\leqslant$ sign is more reasonable?

Comment: @Fedor it is very similar but now specifically asks for the number of $3$.

Comment: Right about your comment on empy in-sets, will modify question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a edge (A,B), and B has at most two incoming edges.  Then A and B must get different colors in order for the inequality to be preserved.  Now have C get an edge from each of A and B.  With no other incoming edges to C or B, this "mini-tournament" must get three colors.

Now add D, E, F so that B and C lead to D, C and D to E, D and E to F.  With no other edges involved, we get a repeated coloring with A and D getting the same color, as do B and E, and C and F.

Now have the snake come and bite its own tail.  Make a bracelet of these vertices.  If we have the number of vertices be a multiple of 3, then a coloring exists.  Otherwise not.

Gerhard "Or Oroubourous Or Orrery Or..." Paseman, 2016.04.02.

Comment: If a snail bites its tail, $B$ gets more than two in-edges, so the whole machinery does not work, does it?

Comment: @Ilya, I think you are hooking it up wrong.  Try this though: have 7 vertices 0 through 6, with (using mod 7 notation) edges (i,i+1) and (i,i+2).  Let me know when you find a coloring for Dominic of this graph.  Gerhard "Do Snails Even Have Tails?" Paseman, 2016.04.02.

Comment: Did you see Fedor's comment about empty $In(v)$? This happens when the indegree is zero.

Comment: Thanks Gerhard, I am trying to see the intuition and partially succeeding, but still have trouble with the snake tail part.

Comment: I do not say your example is wrong; just the reasoning looks strange. Also, the example on 7 vertices does not work (for the new formulation)...

Comment: Does anyone see how to make a full blown answer out of Gerhard's thoughts? I can't see his proof yet...

Comment: Yes, when the inequality is relaxed, I am having trouble finding an uncolorable example.  The closest I have is various pendants coming off a 4-cycle, where one can get some pendants restricted to two colors.  However, connecting these pendants to one another throws things off.  Gerhard "Pendant Dependence Leaves Me Hanging" Paseman, 2016.04.04.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen, when the strict inequality holds, one can have a chain x_0, x_1,... of vertices with edges (x_i,x_i+1) and (x_i,x_i+2) and as a result this limits the permissible partitions to residue classes mod 3. Turn it into a cycle, and then no or one permissible partitions result, depending on the number mod 3 of vertices.  Unfortunately I don't know how to show  the same claim with the weak inequality.  Gerhard "Permissible Partitions Are Strictly Sensitive" Paseman, 2016.04.04.