# Splitting the vertices of undirected graphs into 2 sparse sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

(A version of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235133/partitioning-finite-directed-graphs-into-3-incoming-sparse-sets) for undirected graphs.)

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite, simple, undirected graph. For $v\in V$ set 
$$
  N(v) := \{x\in V: \{x,v\}\in E\}.
$$ 
Is it possible to find a partition $P_1,P_2$ of $V$ such that for every $P_i$ and $v\in P_i$ we have $$|N(v)\cap P_i| \leq |N(v)\cap(V\setminus P_i)|$$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a variant of Lovasz partition lemma. Choose partition $V=P_1\sqcup P_2$ for which the number $E(G|_{P_1})+E(G|_{P_2})$of edges which join vertices of the same part is minimal possible. It works for each vertex $v$: else moving $v$ to other part decreases this value.

Comment: Thanks Fedor--is there a variant of this lemma for directed graphs?

Comment: I wonder myself.